# How to write not "in situ" method with additional template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, inline

I've got the following code (available also at http://ideone.com/6ozZrs):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class MyClass{
    public:
        inline MyClass(const T &t);
        template<class C>
        void MyUberFunction(const C &c)
        {
            std::cout<<"My t: "<<m_t<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Do uber things with: "<<&c<<std::endl;
        }
    private:
        T m_t;
};

template<class T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(const T &t):
    m_t(t)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass<int> myInstance(1337);
    myInstance.MyUberFunction("Another type");

    return 0;
}
```

MyUberFunction method takes a different set of template parameters then its class. How can I split its declaration and definition (as I've done for class constructor)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this syntax for an out-of-class definition:

```
template<class T> // <== The class template parameters first
template<class C> // <== The member function template parameters after
void MyClass<T>::MyUberFunction(const C &c)
{
    std::cout<<"My t: "<<m_t<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Do uber things with: "<<&c<<std::endl;
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t$369) of your modified code compiling.